# 3d mesh model of robot based on joint states

Tags: ros, robot-model, pr2-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to determine the projection of the robot arms (PR2) onto its cameras so that I can mask these regions out of the images. Has anyone done this before? I see some relevant code in the robot_self_filter package but it's not obvious how to proceed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11478/3d-mesh-model-of-robot-based-on-joint-states/) by [joschu](https://answers.ros.org/users/896/joschu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2011-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might take a look at the [camera_self_filter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_self_filter) or [rgbd_self_filter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbd_self_filter) packages.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4